# Can I hard wire two LED shop lights to one power line?

Tags: light-fixture

The room where my boiler is located is currently lit by a simple porcelain lampholder with a switch in the wall. The lampholder is located somewhat near the middle of the long and narrow room. About 10 feet long and 3 feet wide.

I'd like to replace it with an LED shop light that has a short wire coming out the side for hard wiring. (See image below)

My question is: can I wire two shop lights directly to the line source? In other words, can I wire nut 3 wires together (3 black, 3 white, 3 grounds)? Do I need to use the same type of light or can I use different kinds? The wires would all be in the existing ceiling box, covered with a plate that has a hole in the center to allow the light's wire to come through.

[image: LED light]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.  They don't need to be the same.  I mean, one could  be a humdifier unit even.  Just bring the wire in a knockout on the side, and use a listed cable clamp of the type that screws into a knockout.  Don't drill a hole in the box cover, don't hack or homebrew it.

If there are also receptacles on this circuit, make sure the hardwired loads on the circuit don't exceed 50% of circuit capacity.